# Android tab activity View visibility change event

Tags: android, view, visibility, tabview

What is the event dispatched to a View when its visibility changes?

I have a custom View that is attached to a tab. When my custom View becomes invisible because the user switches to other tabs, I want my custom View to be informed.

Comment: I got that: onVisibilityChanged